# Custom title tag in custom post type wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem:

I created a custom post type.
I'd like to have a custom title tag (a cutom post meta).

How do it ?

I have tried to follow tutorial and other question on web but nothing.

I have tried also to modify header.php, but it's show "default" wordpress

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

add a custom meta box to the Custom Post Type.

add this to your functions.php - change **YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE** to your custom post type

```
function add_page_custom_meta_box() {  
$boxTitle = 'Custom Title';
$postType = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE';
    add_meta_box(  
        'page_custom_meta_box', // $id  
        $boxTitle, // $title   
        'show_page_custom_meta_box', // $callback  
        $postType, // $post_type 
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'); // $priority  
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_page_custom_meta_box'); 
$prefix = 'custom_';  
$custom_meta_fields_page = array(
array(  
    'label'  => 'Custom Title',  
    'desc'  => 'Custom Title of the Page.',  
    'id'    => $prefix.'title',  
    'type'  => 'text'  
),  
);  
function show_page_custom_meta_box() {  
global $custom_meta_fields_page, $post;  
// Use nonce for verification  
echo '<input type="hidden" name="page_custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  
      echo '<table class="form-table">';
    // Begin the field table and loop    
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields_page as $field) {  
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post  
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
        // begin a table row with  
        echo '<tr> 
                <th>
                <style>label[for=custom_link-text-to]{color:#00bbe2; text-transform:uppercase;}</style>
                <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th> 
                <td>';  
                switch($field['type']) {
case 'text':  
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break;  
} //end switch  
        echo '</td></tr>';  
    } // end foreach  
    echo '</table>'; // end table  
}

  function save_page_custom_meta($post_id) {  
    global $custom_meta_fields_page;  

    // verify nonce  
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['page_custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;  
    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;  
    // check permissions  
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
            return $post_id;  
    }  

    // loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields_page as $field) {  
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($field['type'] == 'tripple_repeatable')
            $new = array_values($new);
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    } // end foreach  
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_page_custom_meta');
```

then wherever you want the title to display:

```
<?php if ($custom_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_title', true)){echo $custom_title;}?>
```